# Web site cannot handle more than 50 concurrent visitors, what is wrong?

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, nginx-config

My web site will slow down after an e-mailing, when more than 50 visitors arrive at the same time. Then it gets very slow and sometimes gives a 502 Bad Gateway. I tried to change some settings on PHP and NGINX - this didn't solve it.
To be able to see what's happening I installed a tool on the server (Netdata) which gives real time information during 'rush hour'. Also I used a tool to do load testing with 50 concurrent visitors (flood.io)
It appears that when testing starts, CPU usage immediately grows to 100%. Memory is almost, but not used fully, there is about 80Mb available memory left and the swap file is not used yet, which I think is good.

The only log file remarks are:

> WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children,
> there are 0 idle, and 12 total children WARNING: [pool www] server
> reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it  [error]
> 26813#26813: *114871 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
> failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to
> upstream, upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:"

I tried to tune but couldn't make more of it, so I hope this question brings an insight in what to do now. I would expect that more visitors than 50 must be possible. For testing, I copied the site to it's own dedicated VPS, so nothing is slowing it down. What could I do to have it accept some more visitors? Any help would be very much appreciated!

The url on which I'm testing is https://test.parkeer24.nl - the setup is Drupal 8 on Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS), 1 GB RAM, 25 GB SSD, 1 CPU and most of the settings are default.

NGINX 1.14.0 nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level  2;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/xml;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

PHP 7.4 php.ini:

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
serialize_precision = -1
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,pcntl_unshare,
zend.enable_gc = On
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.cookie_samesite =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
```

PHP www.conf:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 15
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
```

Comment: I am not sure but the issue came when there is less File Usage space,  less File physical memory and the CPU overheated for that you need need to maximize the resources

Comment: Yes, more resources surely will bump up the performance. I have a 'live' version of this site running on a server with 12GB ram and 4 cpu's - that allows for about 250 visitors before falling apart. But for such a site I would expect that more visitors than 50 must be possible don't you?

Comment: There's enough physical file space 
root@sv11:~# df -m gives 
/dev/sda1          24636 15913      8708  65%

Comment: Not a solution but could help mitigate : What about using a CDN like cloudflare ?

Comment: As I understand it, Cloudflare would prevent DDOS attacks. But when I send an emailing, the whole purpose of it is to attract more visitors. A site should be able to receive such low numbers.

Comment: You need to increase `pm.max_children`, then the bottleneck will probably be the RAM, 1GB seems very low to handle both php/mysql, you will see the real difference when testing on your live server having 12GB.

Comment: I tested that with the 12Gb server up to 250 children. It didn't help. Point is, shouldn't it be a problem to handle more connections even with a simple setup.